# Creata a UIPickerView. Delegate=self

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *myView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 100, 100)];

    [myView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:myView1];

    UIPickerView *pickerView1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
    pickerView1.delegate = self;
    pickerView1.tag = kVIEW1_PICKERVIEW_TAG;
    pickerView1.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [myView1 addSubview:pickerView1];

    table =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [table addObject:@"Giraffe"];
    [table addObject:@"Water Bottle"];
    [table addObject:@"Sprinning Fan"];
    [table addObject:@"Mairy Monkey"];

    label =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 120, 130, 130)];
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    label.text =@"Label Page";
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:label];

}
```

Comment: Is there a question buried here somewhere?

Comment: -(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView{
 return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *) thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 return [table count];
 
}

Comment: Please post large amounts of code in the original question, not a comment, and... ask an actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of problems. You’ve implemented two of the methods with the wrong names: `-pickView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` should be `-pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`, and `-pickView:titleForRow:forComponent:` should be `-pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:`. Also, you’re setting the picker view’s `delegate`, but you aren’t setting its `dataSource`, so your code that returns the actual items to display isn’t getting called; you need a `pickerView1.dataSource = self;` as well.

Also, as sosborn and Rickay commented, your post is *really* unclear—the only reason I could answer this is because several things are obviously wrong with the code you posted. In general, to get a usable answer on SO, you need to provide more information: what you’re trying to do, exactly what isn’t working, and (ideally) what you’ve tried to fix it thus far. Asking an actual question can help too.